# Can I get bound configuration values from a .net HostApplicationBuilder?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, configuration, startup

Consider the following setup for a console application.

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "MySettings": {
    "MyValue": "Foo"
  }
}
```

MySettings.cs

```
public class MySettings
{
    public string MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

And then in the console app itself:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);

    builder.Services
        .AddOptions<MySettings>()
        .BindConfiguration("MySettings");

    await builder.Build().RunAsync();
}
```

Inside the Main method and after I've created the builder, I can access my config value by using:

```
var foo = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("MySettings:MyValue");
```

But is there any way I can access that value through an instance of the MySettings class? Does the builder make it available in any way after it's been bound?

Comment: Can you please post a [mre] somewhere?

Comment: @GuruStron I'm not sure how I can post an example of something I don't know how to do?

Comment: Ohhh, it seems that I've finally understood what the problem is, sorry =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddOptions` is used to register settings via options pattern (though usually I prefer `Configure` for registration - `builder.Services.Configure<MySettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"))`), so you need to access it accordingly, for example by resolving `IOptions<MySettings>`. For example (just for demonstration, usually you will inject corresponding `IOptions`, `IOptionsMonitor` or `IOptionsSnapshot` in service which needs access to them):

```cs
var build = builder.Build();
var options = build.Services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MySettings>>();
var valueMyValue = options.Value.MyValue; // Foo
await build.RunAsync();
```

Read more:

- [Options pattern in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this - my settings file is available and I can get it usingGetValue but is it possible for me to get it via MySettings.MyValue?

Comment: @BobTway please see the new version of the answer.